# value of the listview item is not appearing in the editext (using fragments)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a fragment with a list view ListViewFragment and another EditorFragment with a Editext. When the activity is created its added the ListViewFragment. Then when a listview item is clicked I want to add the fragment EditorFragment that shows a editext with the value of the listview clicked item. The issue is that when a item in the listview is clicked the EditorFragment appears with the textview but the textview dont displays the value of the listview clicked item. Do you know where is the issue?

**main activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> items= new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        getSupportFragmentManager().
                beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_list,new ListViewFragment()).commit();

    }
}
```

**ListViewFragment**

```
public class ListViewFragment extends Fragment {

    private ListView editor=null;

    static ArrayList<String> items= new ArrayList<>();


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

        editor=(ListView) (result.findViewById(R.id.listView));

        items.add("Item 1");
        items.add("Item 2");

        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        editor.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);



        editor.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {




                EditorFragment editorFragment = new EditorFragment();

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("itemId", i);
                editorFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_list, editorFragment).commit();
            }
        });

        return result;
    }
```

**EditorFragment:**

```
public class EditorFragment extends Fragment {

        private EditText editor=null;


        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            int itemId;

            Bundle args = getArguments();
            if (args  != null && args.containsKey("itemId")) {
               itemId= getArguments().getInt("itemId", -1);
            }

            View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_editor, container, false);

            editor=(EditText) (result.findViewById(R.id.editor));
            editor.setText("hi");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);


            editor.setText(ListViewFragment.items.get(itemId));


            return result;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you hardoded a string and it still doesnt appear theres only one possible error.

You are overriding your theme so the background is white and textColor and colorAccent is also white.

Change the textColor of the EditText to a specific color that you can see.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, its ok pass data between fragments like theese? I check some examples that used interfaces so I dont know if its better with interfaces or if its the same.

Comment: Yes, Parcelables troguh Arguments/Bundle is the correct way